# logout am I missing something?

Tags: vue.js

im not quit sure or not sure how to do it
im trying to logout by removing the jwt or the cookie put not sure if im missing something from the backend or I dont know how to do it in the vue.js and couldt really find anything usefull anywhere else
so some help or understanding to what im missing could be nice

```
<div v-if="this.isLoggedIn">
                <v-btn depressed text v-on:click="logout()">
                    <v-icon left>mdi-logout</v-icon>
                    Logout
                </v-btn>
</div>

export default {
    data: () => ({
        isLoggedIn: true,
        search: "",
    }),
    mounted: function() {
        if (!this.$cookies.get("jwt")) {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        
        
        logout: function() {
            
            
            this.axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', null, { 
            headers: { 
                jwt: this.$cookies.post('jwt'),
            }
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                // user.logout(); dont know this is right?
                this.router.push("/");
            }).catch(err => {
                // Fejled respons
                console.log(err);
                this.$router.push('/dashboard');
            });
            
        },
        
    }
        
};


//backend

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    if(!req.headers.jwt) {
        res.status(403).json({
            message: "Ikke Autoriseret"
        });
        return;
    }

    console.log("/auth -> " + auth.VerifyJwt(req.headers.jwt).email);

    let authObj = auth.VerifyJwt(req.headers.jwt);
    if(!authObj) {
        res.status(403).json({
            message: ""
        });
        return;
    }

    let err, user = await User.findOne({ _id: authObj.id });
    if(err || !user) {
        res.status(403).json({
            message: ""
        });
        return;
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        authorized: true,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        user: user,
        message: "Success"
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to implement your own method for determining whether a user is logged in or not. There is no simple "logout" functionality built into the browser, no. Part of a typical logout would include purging a JWT stored in localStorage, but a cookie should be httpOnly and not at all accessible from the JS, so if you're using a cookie, your backend needs to handle this. The other part of logging out would be in resetting user state and the like.

Comment: alright made a little more sense Im missing alittle bit on the on both ends then, any recommendations to find something that shows this as a example?

Comment: RealWorld front ends is probably a decent place to look: https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld#frontends . Any of the JS ones should be applicable, there's not really much framework specific code in an auth flow.

Comment: FWIW, I've worked on the Preact one recently, and the auth flow looks like this: https://github.com/mutoe/preact-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/store/index.ts#L24-L40 . Logout is as simple as dumping the JWT and then resetting the user state. The user is then sent to the home page at the end.

Answer (score 0):

One way to logout is to have a router link point to the login page as shown below (this can be either in your navigation or anywhere you have the option)

```html
 <router-link to="/">Logout</router-link>
```

Then, in the router, have something like

```html
 {
        path: "/login",
        name: "login",
        component: Thelogin,
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false
        }
      },
```

So, everytime you are signing out, you will be re-directed to the login page, where authentication is not required.

Let me know if this helps, and if not, I can provide alternatives! :-)

Comment: I sadly dont understand that example sorry
the routes look like mine in index.js but im not sure what you are trying to show me